# write a unit case for event.preventDefault using jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am new to jest, i need a help for writing unit case for event.preventDefault using jest in react,
below are the my code,

```
export const removeValuesFromTextAreaEvent = ({ removeValuesFromTextArea }) => (
  event,
  rows
) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  removeValuesFromTextArea({ rowID: rows });
};
```

I am getting

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined.

The test

```
describe("removeValuesFromTextAreaEvent", () => {
  it("returns a function that calls removeValuesFromTextAreaEvent with rows", () => {
    const removeValuesFromTextArea = jest.fn();
    const rowID = 1;
    const event = { preventDefault: jest.fn() };
    removeValuesFromTextAreaEvent({ removeValuesFromTextArea })(event);
    expect(event.preventDefault).toHaveBeenCalled();
    removeValuesFromTextAreaEvent({ rowID, removeValuesFromTextArea })();
    expect(removeValuesFromTextArea).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ rowID });
  });
});
```

Comment: Show the test piece. Where the error is coming from, the running of app or from the jest test.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! below are the my test case code,

Comment: describe("removeValuesFromTextAreaEvent", () => {
  it("returns a function that calls removeValuesFromTextAreaEvent with rows", () => {
    const removeValuesFromTextArea = jest.fn();
    const rowID = 1;

    const event = { preventDefault: jest.fn() };

    removeValuesFromTextAreaEvent({ removeValuesFromTextArea })(event);

    expect(event.preventDefault).toHaveBeenCalled();
    removeValuesFromTextAreaEvent({ rowID, removeValuesFromTextArea })();

    expect(removeValuesFromTextArea).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      rowID
    });
  });
});

Comment: running from jest test

Comment: do you actualy mock the `export const remoevValuesFromTextAreaEvent`? As simply writing the `const removeValuesFromTextArea = jest.fn();` won't work here. You need to mock that module something like here: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions

Comment: Sorry, I didnt get you, Can you help me out more on this, As i am new to jest

Comment: @Santhu you're not passing the event in the second call -> removeValuesFromTextAreaEvent({ rowID, removeValuesFromTextArea })();

Comment: That's great, event error is gone!, but getting this error,

Comment: Expected: {"rowID": 1}
    Received
           1
              Object {
            -   "rowID": 1,
            +   "rowID": undefined,
              },
           2
              Object {
            -   "rowID": 1,
            +   "rowID": undefined,
              },

Comment: any idea what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: you're not passing the `rows` either. Please read carefully your code before posting

Comment: Ok thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the unit test solution:

`index.js`:

```js
export const removeValuesFromTextAreaEvent = ({ removeValuesFromTextArea }) => (event, rows) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  removeValuesFromTextArea({ rowID: rows });
};
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
import { removeValuesFromTextAreaEvent } from './';

describe('removeValuesFromTextAreaEvent', () => {
  it('returns a function that calls removeValuesFromTextAreaEvent with rows', () => {
    const removeValuesFromTextArea = jest.fn();
    const rowID = 1;
    const event = { preventDefault: jest.fn() };
    removeValuesFromTextAreaEvent({ removeValuesFromTextArea })(event, rowID);
    expect(event.preventDefault).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(removeValuesFromTextArea).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ rowID });
  });
});
```

unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61014741/index.test.js (8.616s)
  removeValuesFromTextAreaEvent
    ✓ returns a function that calls removeValuesFromTextAreaEvent with rows (3ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.24s
```